# Как сделать задержку перед выполнением jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пробовал разные костыли, чем не могу найти по размеру. Нужно сделать, чтобы после загрузки страницы через 5 секунд выполнялась функция.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.modal-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
$('.page-wrapper').toggleClass('blur-it');
 return false;  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно через 5 сек запустить функцию, как насчет `setTimeout(fn, ms)` ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(main, 5000);
});

function main() {
    // some code here ...
    alert('Hello');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы js код выполнялся после загрузки страницы используйте **[ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**, а чтобы поставить задержку используйте **[setTimeout](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)** .

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(load, 5000);
});

function load()
{
    $('.modal-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
    $('.page-wrapper').toggleClass('blur-it');
    return false;
}
```